# Calculation of bond spot rates

Tags: interest-rates

the cash prices of six months and one year treasury bills are \$120 and \$115 respectively. A 1.5 years bond that will pay coupons of \$5 every six months currently sells for \$121. A 2 years bond that will pay coupons of \$5  every six months currently sells for  \$ 125. Calculate the six months, 1 year,1.5 years and 2 years spot rates.